# Importar fichero de código sin ejecutarlo #Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa constituido de diversos archivos, para ordenarlo mejor, pero ahora estoy ejecutando un documento que hace los cálculos dentro de otro que los imprime. Pero antes de hacer los cálculos, tengo que cambiar algún valor, por el que ha sido introducido. I me hace los cálculos antes.

Este es mi código del archivo que importa al otro:

```
import archivo_extra

num1 = input("Introduce un numero: ")
num2 = input("Introduce un segundo numero: ")


def imprimir_resultado():
    calculador = archivo_extra.Calcular
    calculador.num1 = num1
    calculador.num2 = num2
    print(f"Resultado: {calculador.resultado}")


imprimir_resultado()
```

Y este es el código del archivo importado:

```
class Calcular:
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 0
    resultado = num1 + num2
```

Obviamente, el programa no es así de simple, i el resultado tiene que imprimirse dentro de una función, porque estoy usando tkinter, i es el comando de un botón.

Comment: Lo que haría falta es crear un método adentro de la clase `Calcular` lo que estás haciendo es inicializar la variable `resultado` con la suma de `num1 + num2` por lo que `resultado` será `0`.

Comment: Cuando importas el archivo extra, el cuerpo de la clase se ejecuta. Crea dos atributos estaticos (num1 y num2) inicializados en 0 y finalmente los suma (0 + 0 = 0) y los guarda en el atributo estatico resultado. Tiempo después de eso, le das nuevos valores a num1 y num2, peeeero resultado sigue valiendo lo mismo. La suma NO se vuelve a hacer. Este es el comportamiento normal de Python. La solución sería crear un método estatico que se encargue de rehacer la suma y devolver el resultado (o darle un nuevo valor a resultado) y llamar a dicho método dentro de la función imprimir_resultado.

Comment: A que os referís con un método estático?
@DanteS.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato

Comment: Buen día @NilMas, creo que las partes y elementos de una clase en python no están claras, [lectura recomendada](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html#:~:text=Las%20clases%20de%20Python%20proveen,clase%20base%20con%20el%20mismo) tanto el comentario de Dante como el mio sugieren que crees un método adentro de la clase para que funcione correctamente. Por favor revisa la URL, yo creo que con eso vas a comprender lo que hace falta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de comenzar a explicar la solución a tu problema, me gustaría decirte que por lo que veo de tu programa, necesitas aprender bien la **Programación Orientada a Objetos en Python** comenzando desde el inicio, ya que estas cometiendo varios errores básicos los cuales son los siguientes:

1. Empecemos por el "archivo_extra", no tienes ningun constructor de la clase que inicialice las variables que vas a utilizar en la clase. Esto sería de la siguiente forma:

   ```
   def __init__(self, num1, num2):
       self.num1 = num1
       self.num2 = num2
   ```
2. Segundo: La clase debe tener métodos que realicen la operación que quieres llevar a cabo. Para este caso se haría de la siguiente forma:

   ```
   def calcular(self):
       return self.num1 + self.num2
   ```

Por lo cual, el código completo del "archivo_extra" quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
class Calcular:
    #Constructor de la clase (Para inicializar las variables)
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    #Método de la Clase (Para ejecutar una acción u operación)
    def calcular(self):
        return self.num1 + self.num2
```

Pasemos a la funcion "imprimir_resultado()" del archivo principal

1. Primero: la función debe recibir los dos argumentos que son los numeros que quieres sumar:

```py
def imprimir_resultado(num1, num2):
```

2. Segundo: Debes instanciar la clase "Calcular" a un objeto (En este caso el objeto se llamará "calculador") y pasar los argumentos que recibes en la función "imprimir_resultado(num1,num2)", esto es para que los argumentos pasen al constructor de la clase **Calcular** y esto inicialice las variables que vas a utilizar dentro de la clase, esto se haría de la siguiente forma:

```py
calculador = archivo_extra.Calcular(num1,num2)
```

3. Al objeto que instanciaste (En este caso "calculador"), debes ejecutar el metodo que quieres utilizar, en este caso sería el método "calcular()", y se haría de la siguiente forma:

```py
print(f"El resultado es: {calculador.calcular()}")
```

*En este caso, imprimí directamente el resultado en la función print*

El código completo del programa principal quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
import archivo_extra

num1 = int(input("Introduce un numero: "))
num2 = int(input("Introduce un segundo numero: "))

def imprimir_resultado(num1, num2):
    calculador = archivo_extra.Calcular(num1,num2)
    print(f"El resultado es: {calculador.calcular()}")

imprimir_resultado(num1,num2)
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo había entendido, mi problema es que no sabía esta parte de teoría por este nombre, y no había dado las gracias porque en Stak Overflow dice que te las ahorres. Aun así, gracias por tu respuesta, ahora me ha quedado aún más claro.